# How to convert an R complex matrix into a numpy array using rpy2

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2

it is clear to me how to convert a float / double R-matrix into a numpy array, but I get an error if the matrix **is complex**.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

m1=robjects.IntVector(range(10))
m2 = robjects.r.matrix(robjects.r['as.complex'](m1), nrow=5)
tmp=np.array(m2, dtype=complex) #ValueError: invalid __array_struct__
```

The problem persists with the following line of code:

```
tmp=np.array(m2)
```

All works fine if the matrix is **not complex**:

```
m2 = robjects.r.matrix(m1, nrow=5)
tmp=np.array(m2)
```

Thanks for any help!

PS: Note that the following dirty trick solves the problem, but does not really answer the question:

```
tmp=np.array(robjects.r.Re(m2))+1j*np.array(robjects.r.Im(m2))
```

PS2: it seems that nobody can answer this question, should we conclude there is a bug in rpy2?

Comment: Quite possibly a bug. Open an issue on rpy2's tracker on bitbucket.

Comment: Can you post the link to the issue?  I find converting `rpy` to `np` can be tricky sometimes. Converting `rpy` to `python` buildins and then convert them to `numpy` rescues (see below).  Might due to `typestr` not being passed correctly to `numpy` `array` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can become tricky to convert `rpy` objects to `numpy`, but it is much more reliable to convert them to `python` objects (`list`, `tuple` etc) first and construct an `array` later.  A solution :

```
In [33]:

import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.reval('m1 <- c(1:10)')
robjects.reval("m2 <- matrix(as.complex(m1), nrow=5)")
np.array(list(robjects.r.m2)).reshape(robjects.r.m2.dim)

Out[33]:
array([[  1.+0.j,   2.+0.j],
       [  3.+0.j,   4.+0.j],
       [  5.+0.j,   6.+0.j],
       [  7.+0.j,   8.+0.j],
       [  9.+0.j,  10.+0.j]])
```